# How to use scala regex pattern matching

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a below String in scala, I want to search and replace value BELL with double quotes "BELL".Iam using replace  but it doesn't work correctly, whats the syntax to use regex that checks the exact search string  from start to end.

my first search is with BELL -> "BELL" and next search will be for BELL.* -> "BELL.*",
my first search replace should update just BELL and second search and replace should update BELL.*

```
val str = "(((( EMP = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))"

str.replace("BELL","""""""+"BELL"+""""""")

( ( ( ( EMP = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL")) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = **"BELL."***)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, use the backslash to escape double quotes.

```
val str = "(((( EMP = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))"
val regex = "BELL((\\.)(\\*))*"
val replaced = str.replaceAll(regex, "\"BELL$2\"")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , but that going to  replace BELL.*  with "BELL".*

Comment: So what do you want to achieve? Can you explain it more clearly? (as an example: input string -> output string). From the question, it is a little bit not clear.

Comment: my input is val str = "(((( EMP = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL) OR ( LASTNAME = BELL)) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))" I want the output to be  "(((( EMP = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL") OR ( LASTNAME = "BELL")) OR ( ( EMPFIRSTNAME = BELL.*)))" , it should not touch the BELL.*

Comment: Ok, as I understand, you need to replace BALL with "BALL", and BELL.*  "BELL."? I've updated my answer

Comment: @Teimuraz. Your laste statement is missing *. so the last line should be      val replaced = str.replaceAll(regex, "\"BELL$2\"$3")

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, I actually I didnt get what does author want to achieve. So from his questions, the goal is probably "my first search is with BELL -> "BELL" and next search will be for BELL.* -> "BELL."

Comment: @Teimuraz, you should include both the answers. I shall upvote if you do. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Regex from the answer handles both cases.